# Pinpoint the area light to object

Tags: light, constraints, parent

I've made an object and put an area light on scene.
I want that area light points toward the object.
I tried to put constraint and PARENT TO OBJECT but that doesn't rotate the light in that specific direction.
How to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To point a light to an object use a **"[Track to](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/tracking/track_to.html)"** constraint.

Set the target to the object you want.

Set

To= -Z

Up = Y

Now the light will always point to the target object.

[image]