# How to direct a lamp into the camera

Tags: objects, camera

In Blender Cycles, it is possible to automatically (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>) put the camera in such a position that the sun's rays shine straight at it. Is it also possible to automatically make the sun rotate so that its rays shine straight at the camera?

Comment: use this technique: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43544/1853 and select the camera as the target for the track to constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow these steps ...

1. Select your sun lamp object.
2. Hit CTRL + Numpad 0 , set sun lamp as default camera.
3. Hit Numpad 0 (Now you are looking from the position of the sun.)
4. Hit CTRL + F, use walk mode to position the lamp
5. LMB or RMB (depending on your mode of selection) to confirm position.

Cheers, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want a Track To constraint on the lamp targeting the object with To=-Z and Up=Y (although any up != Z would be good.)